# accessing tkinter's entry .get() classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm just learning Python. There was a problem that I still couldn't understand. How to pass self.login_field.get() from the Conectad class to the Query Class

```
       
class Connectad(Frame): #Фрейм окна логина и пароля
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        Label(self,text='Логин:').grid(row=0)
        self.login_field = Entry(self,width=30)
        self.login_field.grid(row=0,column=1)
        Label(self,text='Пароль:').grid(row=1)
        self.pw_field = Entry(self,show = '*', width=30)
        self.pw_field.grid(row=1,column=1)
        self.notlogon = Label(self,text='Не верный логин или пароль',fg='red', font=("Arial", 14))
        self.notlogon.grid_remove
        send_button = Button(self, text='Отправить',bg='#4a7abc',
                                                    fg='yellow',
                                                    activebackground='green',
                                                    activeforeground='white',command=self.validationlogin).grid(row=3, column=2, sticky=W, pady=4)
         
    def connad(self): # Подключение к AD
        self.AD_SERVER = 'dc.local'
        self.AD_USER = self.login_field.get()
        self.AD_PASSWORD = self.pw_field.get()
        self.AD_SEARCH_TREE = 'dc=dc,dc=local'
        self.AD_SEARCH_OU = 'ou=USERS,dc=dc,local'
        self.server = Server(self.AD_SERVER, use_ssl=True)
        self.conn = Connection(self.server,user=self.AD_USER,password=self.AD_PASSWORD)
        print(self.conn.bind)
        if not self.conn.bind():
            print('False')
        elif self.conn.bind():
            #print(self.conn)
            self.parent.switch_frame(Query)
        return self.conn
    def user(self):
        self.logi = self.login_field.get()
        print(self.logi)
        return self.logi
```

Need to be sent here:

```
class Query(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent 

    def adoffice(self): # Создание пользователя офис
        get = Connectad()
        get.user()
        print(get.logi)
```

Parent class:

> class App(Tk):
> def **init**(self):
> Tk.**init**(self)
> self._frame = None
> self.switch_frame(Connectad)
>
> ```
> def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
>     new_frame = frame_class(self)
>     if self._frame is not None:
>         self._frame.destroy()
>     self._frame = new_frame
>     self._frame.pack()
> ```

What can you recommend?

Comment: It is not clear when and how `Connectad` and `Query` classes are created and where is the content from `login_field.get()` used in `Query` class?  It is better to provide a [mre].

Comment: all may depend on how you use these classes. You may first create instance of `Query` and later send it as parameter to `Connectad` when you create its instance - and it will have direct access to `Query`. You can also do in other direction: first create instance of `Connectad` and later send it as parameter to `Query` so query will have direct access to `Connectad`. OR `Connectad` may put data in external/global variable or dictionary or class - and `Query` should get this value from this variable/dictionary/class.

Comment: last solution may need to add extra functions to all Frames - ie. `at_start()` - and run it always after changing frame in `switch_frame()`. This way every frame may run `at_start` to update content always when you switch frame. The same way you can create function `at_end()` to run some code when you remove frame in `switch_frame()`

Comment: I think it will be easier to explain.

The Connectad class is responsible for the logging window, into which we enter data and check if there is a connection, opens the following window. In the Query window, we also need the data that we entered. So I need to transfer them there.

Comment: I know how to pass from class to class, but I can't pass a variable with a value to self.login_field.get() or self.pw_field.get() . This is the input data in the logging window.

Comment: I don't understand what *"can't pass a variable with a value to self.login_field.get() or self.pw_field.get()"* means as `self.login_field.get()` returns something you type into the entry box and how can you *pass a variable with a value* to it? As already said, it is better to provide a [mre].

Comment: Fine. I've changed my code to show it more clearly. From the Connectad class I need to pass self.login_field, the data that I entered.

In the Quera class, the AdOffice function should print the value of this field. But it's empty

Comment: You created a *new* instance of `Connectad()` and then get the value using `.user()`.  Getting nothing is expected.  You should use the already created instance of `Connectad()` instead.

Comment: Not working

get = Connectad()
print(get.login_field.get())

Comment: I probably don’t understand how to do it correctly because I’m just learning. But could you help me ;)

Comment: As said, you didn't provide a [mre].  You should have a *parent* class holding the instances of `Connectad` and `Query`.  We cannot identify the issue based on current posted code because it is incomplete.

Comment: add Parent class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your updated code, suggest to pass the user name to class `Query`:

```py
class Connectad(Frame):
    ...

    def connad(self):
        ...
        elif self.conn.bind():
            # pass input user name to class Query
            self.parent.switch_frame(Query, user=self.login_field.get())
        ...

class Query(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent

        # get the user name using keyword argument "user"
        self.user = kwargs.get("user")
        print(self.user)

class App(Tk):
    ...

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class, *args, **kwargs):
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = frame_class(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self._frame.pack()
```

Note that destroying current frame and then creating the new frame is not a good design on switching frame.  Suggest to search StackOverflow on questions about switching frames.